# Quickest way to see if user has a perm set with modify all on the object in question

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I think I could do this with a bunch of queries, but don't want to hit limits.  I  have an LWC where I need to programmatically show a button based on the user's ability to update the record. I've got all other methods accounted for.   I have the record id of the object as input.  Apparently the UserRecordAccess object is not providing the correct answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the record's id, if you have "Modify All" it'll be regardless?

Something like this? Just plug `UserInfo.getUserId()`.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Profile.Name
FROM PermissionSet
WHERE Id IN (SELECT PermissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId = '005...')
AND Id IN (SELECT ParentId FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE SobjectType = 'Case' AND PermissionsModifyAllRecords = true)
LIMIT 1
```

Should find it whether it's a real permset or a hidden one 1:1 linked to profile.